# Is there a way to tag all rows if one column matches a certain value?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am sure there is a better way to explain this, but essentially here's what I am trying to do

```
SELECT
      CASE WHEN INSTR(stringcolumn,'ex33') = 1 then 1 else 0 end as Tag
FROM TABLE
```

Below you is what I am trying to accomplish. If the string is found then I want the 1 to show up in all the rows where the txt_id is the same. What is the best way to accomplish this? I have tried with group by but I cannot figure it out. Any guidance would be appreciated.

[[image: Mock Data1]

Answer (score 1):

You want a window function:

```
SELECT t.*,
       MAX(CASE WHEN stringcolumn LIKE 'ex33%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY txt_id) as tag
FROM TABLE;
```

SQL has the built-in operator `LIKE` which seems clearer than `INSTR()`.

Comment: Question: What if the value in the String Column is txtysh ex33 sjhfhsy. Would the like operator be appropriate here as well?

Comment: You can use `strincolumn like '%ex33%'`.